# Writing in headers and modulating my code

Tags: c, module, header

I can't figure out how to modulate my code by creating .h files and more .c files. Could someone please help me by showing how to create header files for this  ?

What thee code currently does it that if you put in a digit it then displays this in the format of a LSD screen. You can also select the size of the output (e.g, a size 2 means that each column segment and rows is 2 "-" long ) The code also checks as to whether the input is all digits or not. If not it displays "invalid input"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXNUM 50
#define MAXSIZE 100
#define ROWS 3 //From top to bottom
#define COLS 4 // (left to right, up to down)
#define OFF ' '
#define ROW_ON '-'
#define COL_ON '|'

//input number

char led_rows[MAXNUM][ROWS][MAXSIZE];
char led_cols[MAXNUM][COLS][MAXSIZE];
int input_num[MAXNUM];

//Check if integer
int is_digit(char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

//Initalise all rows and columns to be OFF to prevent char array from displaying random signs 
void init_led(int input_count, int size)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < input_count; ++n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                led_rows[n][i][j]= OFF;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < COLS; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            {
                led_cols[n][i][j]= OFF;
            }
        }
    }

}

// Display row of "-" for the needed size amount 
void display_row(int num, int rowNum, int size)
{
    printf(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        //Decides whther row is ON or still OFF
        printf("%c",led_rows[num][rowNum][i]); 
    }
    printf(" ");
}

// Display column of "|" for the needed size amount (number postion,column number,size, number of current column position )
void display_columns(int num, int colNum, int size, int n)
{
    
    printf("%c",led_cols[num][colNum][n]);
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("%c",led_cols[num][colNum+1][n]);
    
}

//Display entire LCD
void display_lcd(int input_count, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    //Goes through first row for input numbers 
    for (int i = 0; i < input_count-1; ++i)
    {
        display_row(i, 0, size);
        printf(" ");
    }
    display_row(input_count-1, 0, size);
    printf("\n");


    
    // print the first two columns for the inputed numbers
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_count-1; ++i)
        {
            display_columns(i, 0, size, n );
            printf(" ");

        }
        display_columns(input_count-1, 0, size, n );
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    //print second row for unputed numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < input_count-1; ++i)
    {
        display_row(i, 1, size);
        printf(" ");
    }
    display_row(input_count-1, 1, size);
    printf("\n");
    
    // print the third and fourth columns for input numbers
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_count-1; ++i)
        {
            display_columns(i, 2, size, n );
            printf(" ");

        }
        display_columns(input_count-1, 2, size, n );
        printf("\n");
    }

    // print last row for inputed numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < input_count-1; ++i)
    {
        display_row(i,2, size);
        printf(" ");
    }
    display_row(input_count-1,2, size);
    printf("\n");
    
}


//Takes in number position, which row, and the size, and it will display "-"
void set_row_on(int num, int row_id,int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {

        led_rows[num][row_id][i] = ROW_ON;
    
    }
}

//Takes in number position, which column, and the size, and it will display "|"
void set_col_on(int num, int col_id, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        led_cols[num][col_id][i] = COL_ON;
        
    }
}

//The setting of the relevent Rows and Columns for the numbers 

void set_on_zero(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    //set_row_on_off(OFF, num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}


void set_on_one(int num, int size)
{
    //set_col_on(0,size, led_cols);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    //set_col_on(2,size, led_cols);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}

void set_on_two(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 2,size);
    
}

void set_on_three(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);

}

void set_on_four(int num, int size)
{
    
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}
void set_on_five(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}

void set_on_six(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}

    void set_on_seven (int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}



void set_on_eight(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_row_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 2,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}

void set_on_nine(int num, int size)
{
    set_row_on(num, 0,size);
    set_row_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 0,size);
    set_col_on(num, 1,size);
    set_col_on(num, 3,size);
}


//Select which number is inputed and which set_on to activate 

void set_led(int input_count, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input_count; ++i)
    {
        if (input_num[i] == 0)
            set_on_zero(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 1)
            set_on_one(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 2)
            set_on_two(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 3)
            set_on_three(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 4)
            set_on_four(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 5)
            set_on_five(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 6)
            set_on_six(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 7)
            set_on_seven(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 8)
            set_on_eight(i, size);
        else if (input_num[i] == 9)
            set_on_nine(i, size);
    }
}

int main (){
    
    int input_count = 0;
    int size;


    printf("LCD calculator display.\n");
    printf("Enter input: ");
    char ch;
    while ((ch=getchar())!='\n')  
    {   
       if (ch==' ')
        continue;
       if(!is_digit(ch))
       {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
            return 1;
       }
       input_num[input_count] = ch - '0';
       input_count++;
    }
    printf("Enter size: ");
    
    if(scanf("%d",&size) != 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid input!\n");
        return 1;
    }

//Set blank
    init_led(input_count,size);
//Set which number to dislplay
    set_led(input_count, size);
//Dsiplay all numbers 
    display_lcd(input_count,size);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly hint: you certainly do **not** want to _modulate_ your code (look it up), but _modularise_ it. :-).

Comment: This is no consulting service. Please read a good C book. If you have a **specific** problem, show a [mcve]. Before that: see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be that you a) share code by placing it in a separate .c file with an accompanying .h file so many other .c files can use the functions of your module and/or b) that you hide the implementation of some complex code in a .c file so the using modules do not have to know the implementation.

In your case you would make a .c file with all the LED functions and a .h file with all the prototypes of the LED functions, then #include the .h file in your main .c file. You should also include the LED .h file in your LED .c file so the compiler will tell you whether the definitions are different from the implementation (which shouldn't).

You should also place the global LED variables and constants in the .h files as `extern` and allocate the variables in your LED .c file.

Don't forget to add the LED .c file to your makefile so it will get compiled.